# position: sticky css вылазит высота самого Элемента (nav) в виде margin, как пофиксить?

Tags: css, position

`position: sticky` вылазит высота самого Элемента (nav) в виде `margin`, как пофиксить?

```css
body {
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  height: 175px;
  width: 22px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  right: 4%;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 10;
}

span {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
}

span:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span:first-child {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="dot dot1"></span>
  <span class="dot dot2"></span>
  <span class="dot dot3"></span>
  <span class="dot dot4"></span>
  <span class="dot dot5"></span>
  <span class="dot dot6"></span>
  <span class="dot dot7"></span>
</nav>
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <section>
    <h1>Coming Soon</h1>
    <p>goplae.co.uk is coming soon but in the meantime check out this page and sign up to our newsletter for more information</p>
    <form action="">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
      <button>Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Даже не представляю как править заголовок. Вообще не понял чем речь в вопросе

Comment: Что значит `высота элемента в виде - margin`?

Comment: Вообщем, меняем nav { position:fixed;} пропадает отступ, который выше секции, при позиции sticky вылазит отступ вверх от первой  секции (бекграунд картинки).
и высота этого отступа равна высоте nav элемента.

Comment: То есть, марджина там нету, просто отступ, в размере высоты самого nav.

Comment: А ты задай элементам `html, body` разный `background` и сразу увидишь в чем разница и почему так

Comment: Спасибо!) сейчас попробую!